# Blazor WASM - Access to fetch at "https://login.microsoftonline.com/...." (redirected from ...) from origin ... has been blocked by "CORS" policy:

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-webassembly, microsoft-identity-platform

I am building a WASM hosted app with multiple clients and started to get the following error when I called a WebApi controller from the Client project.

```
    Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=0e5f2876-c.......-client-SKU=ID_NET6_0&x-client-ver=6.23.1.0' 
    (redirected from 'https://localhost:5001/WeatherForecast') from origin 'https://localhost:5001' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
    Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I ended up working out what the problem was and thought I would document it here as I wasn't able to find a writeup of a similar situation.

My WebApi project was configured as follows. (ie. with AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi and AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp in the same project.)

Program.cs (Server Project)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
```

The project worked fine with just AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi, but started generating the error when I added AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the reason for the error is that the controller that I'm targeting did not know which Authentication Scheme to target.  The CORS message was a red-herring (even though it is technically correct in hindsight).

I had to be explicit in my [Authorize] atrribute as per the following.

```
   [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```